# Proving that $-A^{3}+8A^{2}-21A+18I_{3}=O_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a simple Matrix A, like  \begin{bmatrix}
3 &0  &0 \\ 
 2& -1 &-2 \\ 
 3&  6& 6
\end{bmatrix}

And I want to prove that $-A^{3}+8A^{2}-21A+18I_{3}=O_{3}$

The only way I can solve this is by calculating $-A^{3}$ then $8A^{2}$ etc..

But it takes too much time and I usually make mistakes on the calculations.

Is there a more practical way to solve a problem like this?

*Update*

This is the characteristic polynomial of A: $det(A-\lambda I_{n})= -\lambda^{3}+8\lambda^{2}-21\lambda+18$

It is the same, but how would I explain it?

Comment: Is it diagonalizable?  Perhaps you can diagonalize it and make the calculation much easier.

Comment: I haven't yet reached the chapter where I can check if the matrix is diagonalizable. Would it be easier this way?

Comment: Much easier.  Perhaps you have that you can find a basis of eigen-vectors, and evaluate your polynomial of matrices (which is linear) on this basis and show that it's zero.

Comment: @breeden: Fear not. $A$ is *not* diagonalizable.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I just now realized that.  Too bad.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

EDIT: So do you know a theorem that says something like $p_A(A)=O$ (where $p_A$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$)?

Comment: I was thinking of mentioning this too, but it's unclear if this is the kind of solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: How would I explain the answer. The  characteristic polynomial  of A is the same as the one I want to prove

Comment: Odd.  I never thought someone would know this theorem before learning about diagonalizing a matrix.

Comment: This is the order of my university professor's notes. After this chapter, he mentions diagonalizing

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this so that only **TWO** matrix multiplications are required. Write it as

$$18I - A\cdot(21I - A\cdot(8I - A))$$

I'm assuming scalar multiplication and matrix addition is much easier for you computationally.